# Resource file for en-GB locale doesn't load in C# application

Tags: c#, locale, culture

I am setting the locale of my application using

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

but my "Resource.en-GB.resx" is not loading. It works for en-US, but for en-GB completely ignores it and drops back to the default "Resource.resx" file.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter I double checked and it is installed, I am also in the United Kingdom so PC is running in en-GB lol

Comment: Yes, i've deleted the comment after i've seen where you're from.

Comment: try 'en-gb' instead of 'en-GB'

Comment: @Flakes tried 'en-gb' already and doesn't work. en-CA also works, just not en-GB? It doesn't even fall down to the en language folder like any other en-XX would do it if couldn't find the resource.

Comment: Maybe is stupid, but you checked your ouput folder container this en-GB?

Comment: @ígor Yep definitely there, I have duplicated it for en-CA and this works fine. tried it on a simple test project and this has the same issue using bare bones setup.

Comment: Only thing I can think of as to why this is happening is that my default language and locale is en-gb so it is simply using default. will investigate further to see if i can come up with a useful answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the configuration and should work.

[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-GB")]

See the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.neutralresourceslanguageattribute.aspx

Comment: Yep that was it, makes sense now. I have ended up getting rid of all the en-GB and en resources now and just falling back to the default resource file which is sort of the same behaviour I guess just not having to put in more resource files. Thanks @ctescu